# ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

Tags: apache-kafka

I can't understand what was happening, I set up sasl / scram tls IN KAFKA and do everything according to the instructions. but when running, I get an error and there is nothing useful in the logs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YanD3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Qrv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c5S3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIHkv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWygZ.png)

```
broker.id=0

num.network.threads=3

num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9092
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL

security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/kafka/comfig/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=admin-secret
ssl.key.password=admin-secret
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/kafka/comfig/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=admin-secret
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.secure.random.implementation=SHA1PRNG

log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

num.partitions=1


num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1


offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

log.retention.hours=168

log.segment.bytes=1073741824

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

```
[2021-10-11 19:05:17,955] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2021-10-11 19:05:18,276] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2021-10-11 19:05:18,328] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2021-10-11 19:05:18,331] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:05:18,332] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:05:18,343] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Exception while loading Zookeeper JAAS login context [java.security.auth.login.config=/opt/kafka/config/sasl.jaas.config, zookeeper.sasl.client=default:true, zookeeper.sasl.clientconfig=default:Client]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSaslEnabled(JaasUtils.java:67)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:451)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:233)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    expected [;], read [end of file]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:246)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:245)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSaslEnabled(JaasUtils.java:63)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    expected [;], read [end of file]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.ioException(ConfigFile.java:665)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.match(ConfigFile.java:518)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.parseLoginEntry(ConfigFile.java:501)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.readConfig(ConfigFile.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:329)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135)
    ... 16 more
[2021-10-11 19:05:18,346] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:05:18,352] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-10-11 19:05:18,352] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:05:18,353] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2021-10-11 19:05:18,357] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,307] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,596] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,646] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,649] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,650] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,662] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Exception while loading Zookeeper JAAS login context [java.security.auth.login.config=/opt/kafka/config/sasl.jaas.config, zookeeper.sasl.client=default:true, zookeeper.sasl.clientconfig=default:Client]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSaslEnabled(JaasUtils.java:67)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:451)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:233)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    expected [;], read [end of file]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:246)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:245)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSaslEnabled(JaasUtils.java:63)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    expected [;], read [end of file]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.ioException(ConfigFile.java:665)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.match(ConfigFile.java:518)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.parseLoginEntry(ConfigFile.java:501)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.readConfig(ConfigFile.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:329)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135)
    ... 16 more
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,665] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,671] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,671] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,672] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2021-10-11 19:09:29,672] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:12:35,911] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2021-10-11 19:12:36,335] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2021-10-11 19:12:36,401] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2021-10-11 19:12:36,405] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:12:36,406] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:12:36,419] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Exception while loading Zookeeper JAAS login context [java.security.auth.login.config=/opt/kafka/config/sasl.jaas.config, zookeeper.sasl.client=default:true, zookeeper.sasl.clientconfig=default:Client]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSaslEnabled(JaasUtils.java:67)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:451)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:233)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    expected [;], read [end of file]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:246)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:245)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSaslEnabled(JaasUtils.java:63)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    expected [;], read [end of file]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.ioException(ConfigFile.java:665)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.match(ConfigFile.java:518)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.parseLoginEntry(ConfigFile.java:501)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.readConfig(ConfigFile.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:329)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135)
    ... 16 more
[2021-10-11 19:12:36,423] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:12:36,430] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-10-11 19:12:36,430] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:12:36,431] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2021-10-11 19:12:36,432] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,438] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,734] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,784] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,788] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,788] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,802] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Exception while loading Zookeeper JAAS login context [java.security.auth.login.config=/opt/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf, zookeeper.sasl.client=default:true, zookeeper.sasl.clientconfig=default:Client]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSaslEnabled(JaasUtils.java:67)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:451)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:233)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    Invalid control flag, ТРЕБУЕТСЯ
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:246)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:245)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSaslEnabled(JaasUtils.java:63)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    Invalid control flag, ТРЕБУЕТСЯ
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.ioException(ConfigFile.java:665)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.parseLoginEntry(ConfigFile.java:468)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.readConfig(ConfigFile.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:329)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135)
    ... 16 more
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,805] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,812] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,812] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,813] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2021-10-11 19:12:42,825] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:17:07,832] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2021-10-11 19:17:08,135] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2021-10-11 19:17:08,162] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: inter.broker.listener.name must be a listener name defined in advertised.listeners. The valid options based on currently configured listeners are SASL_SSL
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1781)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1756)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1312)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:34)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:68)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2021-10-11 19:17:41,978] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2021-10-11 19:17:42,288] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2021-10-11 19:17:42,338] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2021-10-11 19:17:42,341] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:17:42,341] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:17:42,356] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Exception while loading Zookeeper JAAS login context [java.security.auth.login.config=/opt/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf, zookeeper.sasl.client=default:true, zookeeper.sasl.clientconfig=default:Client]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSaslEnabled(JaasUtils.java:67)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:451)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:233)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    Invalid control flag, ТРЕБУЕТСЯ
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:246)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:245)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasUtils.isZkSaslEnabled(JaasUtils.java:63)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    Invalid control flag, ТРЕБУЕТСЯ
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.ioException(ConfigFile.java:665)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.parseLoginEntry(ConfigFile.java:468)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.readConfig(ConfigFile.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:329)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135)
    ... 16 more
[2021-10-11 19:17:42,360] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:17:42,365] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-10-11 19:17:42,366] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-11 19:17:42,367] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2021-10-11 19:17:42,374] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Comment: Please show your configs and logs as text. not images

Answer (score 1):

At least I think you should add a semicolon at the end of Kafka Server entry in the sasl jaas config file.